# Track the Google ranking via API

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo

I want to track how key search terms are performing in Google?

Currently I do a manual search and note the page number and position in results.

However, I am keen to automate this. Does Google have an API for this purpose, I can't find one that looks suitable but this surprises me.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it [Google Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) that you are looking for?

Comment: @Hemal Pandya: That API is for Google Custom Search, not the standard Google search.

Comment: If this is possible then you are attempting to do something that is not supported or advised by Google.

Answer (score 2):

@Eddy, You can use products like AuthorityLabs, SEscout, SearchEnabler for keyword tracking and more SEO related stuff.